# Trying to Learn MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to do [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2941/how-to-write-a-simple-phpmysql-web-service-for-an-ios-app), and I've gotten as far as to have a MySQL preference pane and I have apparently started a MySQL server, but I'm unsure of how to proceed.

In the tutorial it says...

> Here are the MySQL statements you’ll need to create these tables:
>
> ```
> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS rw_promo_code;
> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS rw_app;
> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS rw_promo_code_redeemed;
>
> CREATE TABLE rw_promo_code (
>     id mediumint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
>     rw_app_id tinyint NOT NULL, 
>     code varchar(255) NOT NULL,
>     unlock_code varchar(255) NOT NULL,
>     uses_remaining smallint NOT NULL
> );
>
> CREATE TABLE rw_app (
>     id mediumint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
>     app_id varchar(255) NOT NULL
> );
>
> CREATE TABLE rw_promo_code_redeemed (
>     id mediumint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
>     rw_promo_code_id mediumint NOT NULL,
>     device_id varchar(255) NOT NULL,
>     redeemed_time TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
> );
> ```

However, I don't know where these statements should be used (I can tell just from the use of whitespace and newlines they are not for the terminal).

Where should I use these commands to create my tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use an SQL console application. I recommend [MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/)

Also [here is a tutorial](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-getting-started-tutorial.html) on how to use it.